# Different width `th` & `td` in Table

Tags: html, css

My problem is to put for example `th` at `50px` and `td` at `500px`, is this at least possible?

For my problem, i use `datatable` but so that most people can be reply i share a simply code :

```css
.abc {
  width: 500px;
}

.def {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> Data Table </title>

</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>dkjg</th>
        <th class="def">fdsg</th>
        <th>dsgs</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>sdkhgdlg</td>
        <td class="abc">dsghj</td>
        <td>dfsjhn</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>sdkhgdlg</td>
        <td class="abc">dsghj</td>
        <td>dfsjhn</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an image of the desired result? How should the 3rd column behave in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. All columns in the table will always have the same width.

You can possibly do this by declaring two separate tables. Table 1for the header and table 2 for the contents.